# Interpolate position from DataFrame using position before and after datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame containing datetime position data for multiple vehicles. The datetime is not contiguous and there are multiple vehicles in the same data set. The data set is very large so I am not certain resampling at regular intervals is really a viable option.

```
     date_time                     uid   lat    lon
1    2017-09-26 18:23:00.000       ABC   1.00   1.00
2    2017-09-26 18:23:12.000       ABC   1.20   1.20   
3    2017-09-26 18:23:48.000       ABC   1.40   1.40
4    2017-09-26 18:23:52.000       ABC   1.50   1.50
5    2017-09-26 18:23:01.000       DEF   0.10   0.10
6    2017-09-26 18:23:04.000       DEF   0.11   0.11
7    2017-09-26 18:23:24.000       DEF   0.30   0.30
8    2017-09-26 18:23:28.000       DEF   0.32   0.32
9    2017-09-26 18:23:40.000       DEF   0.40   0.40
10   2017-09-26 18:23:03.000       GHI   5.70   5.70
11   2017-09-26 18:23:12.000       GHI   5.80   5.80
12   2017-09-26 18:23:24.000       GHI   5.90   5.90
13   2017-09-26 18:23:30.000       GHI   6.00   6.00
14   2017-09-26 18:24:30.000       JKL   0.00   0.00
15   2017-09-26 18.24.35.000       JKL   1.00   1.00
```

What I'd like to be able to do is fetch the position before and after/equal to a given datetime value so that I can interpolate the possible position at that time. Something like:

```
target_time = '2017-09-26 18:23:12'
mask = df['date_time'] < target_time LIMIT 1 per UID?? & df['date_time'] >= target_time LIMIT 1 per UID??
points = df[mask]

      date_time                     uid   lat    lon
 1    2017-09-26 18:23:00.000       ABC   1.00   1.00
 2    2017-09-26 18:23:12.000       ABC   1.20   1.20   
 6    2017-09-26 18:23:04.000       DEF   0.11   0.11
 7    2017-09-26 18:23:24.000       DEF   0.30   0.30
 10   2017-09-26 18:23:03.000       GHI   5.70   5.70
 11   2017-09-26 18:23:12.000       GHI   5.80   5.80
```

This is pretty straight forward with a loop but its incredibly slow and I'm sure there is a much smarter solution. Perhaps it can be done in a single operation even.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
data_time - targer_time
2.
Find smallest positive and smallest negative for each id

Comment: Is there a way of doing step 2 here without using a loop?

Comment: Filter all positive. Group by id. Sort by delta. Take first feom each group. Same to negative